# Is the ArcMap Spatial Bookmark feature or something similar available in Inkscape?

Tags: bookmarks, inkscape

When editing text in maps in Inkscape I wish I could have view/spatial based bookmarks as is available in ArcMap.

For example: Quickly zooming into the text at various parts of the map.

Answer (score 1):

This exact feature is not available in Inkscape. The various zoom options found in the `View > Zoom` menu are the closest thing you can get.